# Define a predicate inside a predicate in prolog

Tags: lambda, prolog, metaprogramming, predicate

I'm trying to define a predicate inline to pass it to another predicate in Prolog.

```
% Test if a "product" of graphs G1 and G2 has a "mini-loop" starting from Q
test_property_combined(G1,G2,Q):-
    (g12(Q1,Q2) :- combine(G1,G2,Q1,Q2)),
    some_property(g12,Q).
```

*(The syntax above is obviously wrong.)*

Later on `g12` would be invoked by `call`

```
% Test if a graph G has a "mini-loop" starting from Q
some_property(G,Q):-
    Goal1 =.. [G,Q,C],
    Goal2 =.. [G,C,Q],
    call(Goal1),
    call(Goal2).
```

The problem persists because i want to test `some_property` on some kind of an aggregation of previously defined predicates.

```
% Create a "product" of graphs G1 and G2
combine(G1,G2,(Q1,Q2),(Q3,Q4)):-
    Goal1 =.. [G1,Q1,Q3],
    Goal2 =.. [G2,Q2,Q4],
    call(Goal1),
    call(Goal2).
```

The mentioned predicates and an example of a test query:

```
% g1 and g2 are graphs
g1(a,b).
g1(b,a).

g2(c,d).
g2(d,c).


?- test_property_combined(g1,g2,(a,c)).
```

How does one go about doing it?

Comment: Sorry, I can't get the point. Do you know about [lambda](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl) ?

Comment: No, but it seems a bit of an overkill to use it here. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: Do not use `(=..)/2` to emulate higher-order programming. Use call/N instead. It is much more general and permits to use [`library(lambda)`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure to get the point, but this works :

```
test_property_combined(G1,G2,Q):-
    assert((g12(Q1,Q2) :- combine(G1,G2,Q1,Q2))),
    some_property(g12,Q).
```

Ok, may be something like that

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

test_property_combined(G1,G2,Q):-
    % (g12(Q1,Q2) :- combine(G1,G2,Q1,Q2)),
    Pred = \Z^T^combine(G1,G2,Z,T),
    some_property(Pred,Q).


combine(G1,G2,(Q1,Q2),(Q3,Q4)):-
    Goal1 =.. [G1,Q1,Q3],
    Goal2 =.. [G2,Q2,Q4],
    call(Goal1),
    call(Goal2).


some_property(G,Q):-
    call(G, Q, C),
    call(G, C, Q).
```

Last edit (hope so) with full code :

```
test_property_combined(G1,G2,Q):-
    some_property(combine(G1,G2),Q).

combine(G1,G2,(Q1,Q2),(Q3,Q4)):-
    call(G1,Q1,Q3),
    call(G2,Q2,Q4).

some_property(G,Q):-
    call(G, Q, C),
    call(G, C, Q).

g1(a,b).
g1(b,a).

g2(c,d).
g2(d,c).
```

@false => useful remarks, as usual !

Comment: Don't forget to clean up by retracting the temp predicate.

Comment: Yes with **retractall(g12(__,__))**.

Comment: Thanks, this works. This actually is a watered down version of my actual code, but i hoped here it would still make sense to need to define a predicate inline.

Comment: -1: This definition is broken: What happens if test_property_combined/3 will be called inside combine/4? Also, when do you retractall/1 the definition? You should use call/N and something along [`library(lambda)`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl).

Comment: And: there is no difference to adding g12/2 as a static rule.

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail what happens when `combine(G1,G2)` is passed to some_property/2 if the definition i have is for combine/4 not combine/2? I think my understanding of what can be used as a term in Prolog is lacking.

Comment: @RihardsKrišlauks: Within some_property/2 combine(G1,G2) will be called like so: call(combine(G1,G2),Q,C) which effectively calls combine(G1,G2,Q,C)

Comment: @joel76: combine/4 still can be improved by removing (=..)/2.

Comment: @false can this be further extended to allow for switching the arguments in places? E.g. the head of combine/4 was `combine((Q3,Q4),(Q1,Q2),G1,G2)` instead of `combine(G1,G2,(Q1,Q2),(Q3,Q4))`. If so, then it seems to be a bit of hack-ish and not to support a more general case; hence, assert/1 would seem more appropriate.

Comment: @Rihards: You need lambda if the arguments are not in the perfect order and when you want to add some more to it. But pay attention to the scoping of variables: Above, it should be  rather `Pred = {G1,G2}+\Z^T^combine(G1,G2,Z,T),`